# how to access python variables from outside the script

Tags: python, linux, conky

I am using a python script that runs in a curses wrapper loop. I would like to have a conky display show the values of various str vars in the script, updating every second. I know i could have the python script write data to a text file and have conky read the file, but that seems inefficient and unscalable. What are some ways to do this without text files? I imagine using sockets or pipes and a helper script called from conky like this

```
${exec "helper.py --get-variable=var_a"}
```

I havent found much on how to do this. I am on manjaro linux. What is the best way?

Comment: After imagining, start to put the image into some form of reality, and if that doesn't do what you want, post code here.

Comment: I think having your script write values to a file is probably the easiest solution, and not any less efficient than a complicated contraption built from pipes and sockets.

Comment: If your file is in a tmpfs filesystem like `/run` or `/tmp`, it will be pretty efficient.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it works pretty well, with the advantage of simplicity.